# Using JavaScript with Google API: , getting user selected input from list events

Tags: javascript, api, google-calendar-api

Let me preface this by saying that I am a complete novice, so if this is an obvious answer then I apologize in advance but I couldn't find anything after spending about a week of searching.

I'm currently working with the Google Calendar API to design an application that uses JavaScript to list events for a particular date chosen by the user. I have Google's Quickstart documents up and running and I'm currently editing it to see how it works.

Basically I've designed a form in HTML and I'm trying to use JavaScript to get elements and use them to submit the necessary parameters to google. Right now I'm just trying to get it to accept inputted data from:

```
<label>Date: </label>
<input type="date" id="dateFirst" name="dateFirst">
```

to go into here:

```
function listUpcomingEvents() {
            gapi.client.calendar.events.list({
                'calendarId': 'primary',
                'timeMin': (new Date()).toISOString(),
                'showDeleted': false,
                'singleEvents': true,
                'maxResults': 50,
                'orderBy': 'startTime'
            }).then(function(response) {
                var events = response.result.items;
                appendPre('Upcoming events:');
```

I know it needs to go into the 'timeMin' section, and that I probably need to assign a 'timeMax' as well, but I've tried several formats like this

```
(new Date(inputDate)).toISOString()
```

and all of them end up just breaking the script.

I've tried creating some new variables that use the getElementById method to pull information into the listUpcomingEvents() function, but that doesn't seem to help. These variables are listed below:

```
var inputDate = document.getElementById('dateFirst');
var inputLogin = document.getElementById('myText');
var inputPassword = document.getElementById('myPwd');
var inputName = document.getElementById('senName');
```

I am totally lost and I've got a long way to go on this before I can get it working, I've still got to get it to accept login information from the  tags as well, but I'd like to try to make some progress on just getting it to list events only from the selected day first.

Am I even on the right track? Any input/help/guidance would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

You can find the full code below:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
    <title>Calendar Card Test</title>
    <meta charset='utf-8' />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="test.css" />
</head>

<body>
    <p id="testName">JavaScript Test Calendar</p>

    <div>
        <form id="topInput">
            <fieldset>
                <legend>Text input</legend>
                <p>
                    <label>Login: </label>
                    <input type="text" id="myText" value="Login info here" />
                </p>
                <p>
                    <label>Password: </label>
                    <input type="password" id="myPwd" value="secret" />
                </p>
                <p>
                    <label>Date: </label>
                    <input type="date" id="dateFirst" name="dateFirst">
                </p>
                <p>
                    <label>Name: </label>
                    <input type="text" id="senName" value="Name" />
                </p>

            </fieldset>
        </form>
    </div>


    <!--Add buttons to initiate auth sequence and sign out-->

    <input type="submit" value="Log in" id="authorize-button">
    <input type="submit" value="Sign-Out" id="signout-button">
    <pre id="content"></pre>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        // Client ID and API key from the Developer Console
        var CLIENT_ID = 'CIENT_ID';

        // Array of API discovery doc URLs for APIs used by the this application
        var DISCOVERY_DOCS = ["https://www.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis/calendar/v3/rest"];

        // Authorization scopes required by the API; multiple scopes can be
        // included, separated by spaces.
        var SCOPES = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.readonly";

        var authorizeButton = document.getElementById('authorize-button');
        var signoutButton = document.getElementById('signout-button');

        // Set variables to get data from <input> tags
        var inputDate = document.getElementById('dateFirst');
        var inputLogin = document.getElementById('myText');
        var inputPassword = document.getElementById('myPwd');
        var inputName = document.getElementById('senName');


        /**
         *  On load, called to load the auth2 library and API client library.
         */
        function handleClientLoad() {
            gapi.load('client:auth2', initClient);
        }

        /**
         *  Initializes the API client library and sets up sign-in state
         *  listeners.
         */
        function initClient() {
            gapi.client.init({
                discoveryDocs: DISCOVERY_DOCS,
                clientId: CLIENT_ID,
                scope: SCOPES
            }).then(function() {
                // Listen for sign-in state changes.
                gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().isSignedIn.listen(updateSigninStatus);

                // Handle the initial sign-in state.
                updateSigninStatus(gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().isSignedIn.get());
                authorizeButton.onclick = handleAuthClick;
                signoutButton.onclick = handleSignoutClick;
            });
        }

        /**
         *  Called when the signed in status changes, to update the UI
         *  appropriately. After a sign-in, the API is called.
         */
        function updateSigninStatus(isSignedIn) {
            if (isSignedIn) {
                authorizeButton.style.display = 'none';
                signoutButton.style.display = 'block';
                listUpcomingEvents();
            } else {
                authorizeButton.style.display = 'block';
                signoutButton.style.display = 'none';
            }
        }

        /**
         *  Sign in the user upon button click.
         */
        function handleAuthClick(event) {
            gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().signIn();
        }

        /**
         *  Sign out the user upon button click.
         */
        function handleSignoutClick(event) {
            gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().signOut();
        }

        /**
         * Append a pre element to the body containing the given message
         * as its text node. Used to display the results of the API call.
         *
         * @param {string} message Text to be placed in pre element.
         */
        function appendPre(message) {
            var pre = document.getElementById('content');
            var textContent = document.createTextNode(message + '\n');
            pre.appendChild(textContent);
        }

        /**
         * Print the summary and start datetime/date of the next ten events in
         * the authorized user's calendar. If no events are found an
         * appropriate message is printed.
         */

        function listUpcomingEvents() {
            gapi.client.calendar.events.list({
                'calendarId': 'primary',
                'timeMin': (new Date(inputDate)).toISOString(),
                'showDeleted': false,
                'singleEvents': true,
                'maxResults': 50,
                'orderBy': 'startTime'
            }).then(function(response) {
                var events = response.result.items;
                appendPre('Upcoming events:');

                if (events.length > 0) {
                    for (i = 0; i < events.length; i++) {
                        var event = events[i];
                        var when = event.start.dateTime;
                        if (!when) {
                            when = event.start.date;
                        }
                        appendPre(event.summary + ' (' + when + ')')
                    }
                } else {
                    appendPre('No upcoming events found.');
                }
            });
        }
    </script>
    <script async defer src="https://apis.google.com/js/api.js" onload="this.onload=function(){};handleClientLoad()" onreadystatechange="if (this.readyState === 'complete') this.onload()">
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You're on the right track by using the `document.getElementById()` function. You're so close!

`document.getElementById()` returns the *element* that has that id attribute. Text box and text area elements have a `value` attribute that will return the user's input from the text box.

The changes you would have to make are simply:

```
var inputDate = document.getElementById('dateFirst').value;
var inputLogin = document.getElementById('myText').value;
var inputPassword = document.getElementById('myPwd').value;
var inputName = document.getElementById('senName').value;
```

[Here is some further reading from w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_text_value.asp).

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to explain that Robert! I really appreciate it. I get kind of overwhelmed with all the documentation. There's so much it's easy to forget small things like that.